# Hyperlink the first result of an SQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am hoping to add a link to one of the results this query outputs.

```
<?php $tpw = "SELECT PLAYER, YEAR, WEEK, SUM(POINTS) ";
    $tpw .= " FROM SCHEDULE";
    $tpw .= " WHERE OWNER = 'BRANDON' ";
    $tpw .= " GROUP BY YEAR, WEEK, PLAYER ";
    $tpw .= " ORDER BY SUM(POINTS) DESC ";
    $tpw .= " LIMIT 5";
    $tpwresult = mysqli_query($con, $tpw);
    //test for query error
    if (!$tpwresult){
        die("Database Query Failed!");
    }?>


    <table class="weeks">
    <th colspan="4">Most Points in a Week (Player)</th>
    <tr><td>Year</td><td>Week</td><td>Player</td><td>Points</td></tr>
        <?php while($tpwrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tpwresult)){?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $tpwrow ["YEAR"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tpwrow ["WEEK"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tpwrow ["PLAYER"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tpwrow ["SUM(POINTS)"];?></td></tr>
<?php } ?></table>
```

Is it possible to hyperlink only the first row/result of this table?

Comment: Hyperlink to what link?

Comment: YouTube - The exact link for this example would be: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiZXjcb77Qw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most efficient code, but kept it simple

```
<table class="weeks">
<th colspan="4">Most Points in a Week (Player)</th>
<tr><td>Year</td><td>Week</td><td>Player</td><td>Points</td></tr>
    <?php $first=1
    while($tpwrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tpwresult)){?>
<tr><td><?php echo $tpwrow ["YEAR"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $tpwrow ["WEEK"];?></td>

<td>
<?php if ($first == 1) }?>
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiZXjcb77Qw'>
<?php }?>
<?php echo $tpwrow ["PLAYER"];?>
<?php if ($first == 1) {?>
</a>
<?php $first = 0;}?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $tpwrow ["SUM(POINTS)"];?></td></tr>
<?php } ?></table>
```

Comment: Awesome - that worked! If I wanted to do the same thing for say the 3rd result, this wouldn't work, correct?

Comment: Correct. You can simply change `$first` to `$counter` and increment it on each iteration inside the `while` then change the `if` to `if ($counter==3)` and remove the line `$first = 0`. Care to try yourself?

Comment: Tried it and loved it. Thanks! http://theshowffl.com/history.php The linked rows are 3/4 down. Also, the page loads incredibly slow; issue for another day :-)